# How to customize cufflinks output columns

Tags: customization, sequence

I am analyzing RNAseq data of mouse using mm10. I started with tophat2/bowtie. Then I ran cufflinks to generate the FPKM of genes and isoforms. I am using a gtf file that has the genebiotype (i.e. whether it is a pseudogene, protein coding, snRNA, lincRna...) in the second column as well as within the line next to gene names. Example of a line of my GTF is:

```
1   unprocessed_pseudogene  exon    3054233 3054733 .   +   .   exon_id "ENSMUSE00000848981"; exon_number "1"; gene_biotype "pseudogene"; gene_id "ENSMUSG00000090025"; gene_name "Gm16088"; gene_source "havana"; tag "mRNA_start_NF"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000160944"; transcript_name "Gm16088-001"; transcript_source "havana"; tss_id "TSS82763";
1   unprocessed_pseudogene  transcript  3054233 3054733 .   +   .   gene_biotype "pseudogene"; gene_id "ENSMUSG00000090025"; gene_name "Gm16088"; gene_source "havana"; tag "mRNA_start_NF"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000160944"; transcript_name "Gm16088-001"; transcript_source "havana"; tss_id "TSS82763";
1   snRNA   exon    3102016 3102125 .   +   .   exon_id "ENSMUSE00000522066"; exon_number "1"; gene_biotype "snRNA"; gene_id "ENSMUSG00000064842"; gene_name "Gm26206"; gene_source "ensembl"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000082908"; transcript_name "Gm26206-201"; transcript_source "ensembl"; tss_id "TSS81070";
1   snRNA   transcript  3102016 3102125 .   +   .   gene_biotype "snRNA"; gene_id "ENSMUSG00000064842"; gene_name "Gm26206"; gene_source "ensembl"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000082908"; transcript_name "Gm26206-201"; transcript_source "ensembl"; tss_id "TSS81070";
```

My cufflinks gene and isoform tracking output file looks like this:

```
tracking_id     class_code      nearest_ref_id  gene_id gene_short_name tss_id  locus   length  coverage        FPKM    FPKM_conf_lo    FPKM_conf_hi    FPKM_status
ENSMUSG00000090025      -       -       ENSMUSG00000090025      Gm16088 TSS82763        1:3054232-3054733       -       -       0       0       0       OK
ENSMUSG00000064842      -       -       ENSMUSG00000064842      Gm26206 TSS81070        1:3102015-3102125       -       -       0       0       0       OK
ENSMUSG00000025900      -       -       ENSMUSG00000025900      Rp1     TSS11475        1:4343506-4360314       -       -       0       0       0       OK
ENSMUSG00000088333      -       -       ENSMUSG00000088333      Gm22848 TSS18078        1:3783875-3783933       -       -       0       0       0       OK
ENSMUSG00000025902      -       -       ENSMUSG00000025902      Sox17   TSS56047,TSS74369       1:4490927-4496413       -       -       0.611985        0.394887        0.829082        OK
ENSMUSG00000051951      -       -       ENSMUSG00000051951      Xkr4    TSS1201,TSS70682,TSS88403       1:3205900-3671498       -       -       0       0       0       OK
```

As you can see, it lacks the second column of the gtf which indicates the type of the gene product. Is there anyway to have cufflinks automatically incorporate this into its output files? It doesn't seem there is a simple command for that unless I am missing it. please advise-

Answer (score 0):

I tried several methods to get this to work directly while running cufflinks but none worked (if anyone has a solution, let me know). However, i found a way around it. what i did is the following:
1- After running all your cufflinks commands, merge the data by FPKM column to another file (i have a script written for this - if anyone wants it , let me know).
2- Download the function table from UCSC table browser
3- Add that column using the commands below to the merged output above

```
Comb_Iso = pd.read_csv('Combined.Isoforms.txt', sep='\t') # reads in combined cufflinks output
fnc_library = pd.read_csv(args.library, sep='\t', usecols=[0,1] ) #only takes first 2 columns #reads in the path to the function library
Comb_Iso_fnc = Comb_Iso.merge(fnc_library, on='TranscriptID', how='left') #merges them
ncol_CIF = len(Comb_Iso_fnc.columns) 
df_iso=Comb_Iso_fnc.iloc[:,[0, 1, ncol_CIF-1] + list(range(2,ncol_CIF-1))]
df_iso.to_csv(args.output_combined.strip()+'.Isoforms.txt',  index=False, sep="\t") #generates the output.
```

Example of the output now is:

```
TranscriptID    GeneID  Function    GeneName    TSS-ID  Locus-ID    ExampleHeader1  ExampleHeader2  ExampleHeader3
ENSMUST00000115488  ENSMUSG00000088000  protein_coding  Gm25493 TSS84820    1:4723276-4723379   9   9   9
ENSMUST00000027042  ENSMUSG00000096126  protein_coding  Gm22307 TSS39629    1:4529016-4529123   8   8   8
ENSMUST00000140302  ENSMUSG00000025902  Test2   Sox17   TSS56047,TSS74369   1:4490927-4496413   5   5   5
ENSMUST00000115484  ENSMUSG00000051951  protein_coding  Xkr4    TSS1201,TSS70682,TSS88403   1:3205900-3671498   6   6   6
ENSMUST00000135046  ENSMUSG00000089699  protein_coding  Gm1992  TSS23899    1:3466586-3513553   7   -7  -7
ENSMUST00000132064  ENSMUSG00000025900  linc    Rp1 TSS11475    1:4343506-4360314   3   -3  -3
ENSMUST00000072177  ENSMUSG00000090025      Gm16088 TSS82763    1:3054232-3054733   1   1   1
ENSMUST00000082125  ENSMUSG00000064842  protein_coding  Gm26206 TSS81070    1:3102015-3102125   2   2   2
```

You can see the function in the 3rd column. 
Would be glad to share any of my scripts to combine cufflinks out put (although these may not be the best, still working on optimizing) if you want them.